# Manual importhtml()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importhtml

I'm tired of Google Sheets re-triggering my importHTML functions every time I make a change to my sheet, so I would like to make that function happen manually, and store the returned data until the next time the function is manually called.

[I previously asked about how to do this with `importJSON()`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108818/how-to-make-importjson-leave-existing-data-alone-if-calculation-not-performed) and that solution works well, but I haven't been able to modify it to work with `importhtml()`.  Here is the code I have at the moment that returns nothing:

```
function mImportHTML(url, query, index) {
  return "Imported data below this cell";
}

function updateImportHTML() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      if (/^=mImportHTML/i.test(formulas[i][j])) {
        var data = eval("ImportHTML" + formulas[i][j].slice(12));
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, j + 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`mImportHTML()` is just "Manual ImportHTML".

My sample call in Sheets is `=mImportHTML("http://www.apmex.com/category/50000/other-items","table",1)`

Unfortunately I'm not very good with JS so I haven't been able to figure out why this is failing.  It seems to me that it should work just like the `importJSON()` code but for some reason it doesn't.  I'd appreciate any help in getting this going!

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because spreadsheet functions like importHTML can't be calculated by Google Apps Script.

The [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) it's able to get content from a URL. Once the script got the content, it should parse it, but there is a problem, Google Apps Script doesn't include a robust method that work with any web page.

If the web page to import is XHTML then you could try to use the [Class XMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service). Another alternative is to try to use JavaScript regular expressions but HTML isn't a regular language, so this could not be easy.

Related question on Stack Oveflow: [What is the best way to parse html in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19455158/1595451)

Comment: Ugh... that doesn't sound promising.  I did discover at least that my error was due to case sensitivity of my function name in the eval().  However now it simply returns nothing rather than any error.  Sounds like this is a dead end... what a shame.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, and have developed the following Google Script as a solution:

### The script:

```
// inspired by: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90908/importxml-data-reloading-every-time-i-open-the-sheet

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [
    {name: "Update imported data", functionName: "update_imported_data"},
    {name: "Disable Formulas", functionName: "disable_formulas"},
    {name: "Enable Formulas", functionName: "enable_formulas"}
  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function update_imported_data() {
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

  // if (currentSheetName.indexOf("-formula")>-1) {
  if (/-formula/i.test(currentSheetName)) {
    var formulaSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var dataSheetName = currentSheetName.split(new RegExp("-formula",'i'))[0];
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSheetName);
  } else {
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var formulaSheetName = currentSheetName + "-formula";
    var formulaSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(formulaSheetName);
  }

  var rangeImportHtml = formulaSheet.getRange(1,2, formulaSheet.getLastRow(),1);
  enable_formulas(formulaSheet)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var rangeFormula = formulaSheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 1);
  var rangeData = dataSheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 1);
  rangeFormula.copyTo(rangeData, {contentsOnly: true});
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  disable_formulas(formulaSheet);
}

function disable_formulas (formulaSheet) {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (typeof formulaSheet == 'undefined') {var formulaSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();}
  var range = formulaSheet.getDataRange();
  var textFinder = range.offset(1,0).createTextFinder("^=").useRegularExpression(true).matchFormulaText(true);
  textFinder.replaceAllWith("`=");
}

function enable_formulas (formulaSheet) {
  // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (typeof formulaSheet == 'undefined') {var formulaSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();}
  var range = formulaSheet.getDataRange();
  var textFinder = range.offset(1,0).createTextFinder("^`=").useRegularExpression(true).matchFormulaText(true);
  textFinder.replaceAllWith("=");
}
```

Select the menu item **Extensions** > **Apps Script** and paste the script there.

### Explanation

The script's main function is to basically disable all the formulas in the selected sheet after copying their results into another sheet, thus generating static data, *that can be updated* by re-running the script.

**It will create a custom menu on the menu bar with the functions:**

- Update imported data.
- Disable Formulas.
- Enable Formulas.

**So here is what you have to do:**

- Write the formulas (including: ImportHTML, ImportJSON, etc..) as usual in the sheet (e.g. `Sheet1`) as usual. This is the sheet where the static data will be stored, the "Data Sheet".
- Duplicate the sheet and change the name of the new sheet to match the original name and add `-formula`. The name is now `Sheet1-formula`. This is the sheet where the (disabled) formulas will be stored, the "Formulas Sheet".
- Run the the function `Update imported data` in either sheet ("Data Sheet" or "Formulas Sheet") and the script will copy the data generated in the "Formulas Sheet" into the "Data Sheet", and then disable the formulas by appending them with `` ` ``.

**You can then run the function again in either sheet to update the data. It will automatically enable the formulas, copy their results, and re-disable the formulas.**

The other 2 functions, `Disable Formulas` & `Enable Formulas` are for manually disabling and enabling the formulas in the active sheet, regardless of the sheet's name or contents.